# Flot jQuery start xaxis label NOT located below first tick

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, flot

In xAxis labels,  I have a set the graph to display the labels every 3 days by setting below in xaxis:

```
 xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
        tickSize: [1.9, "day"],
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w8eob27d/).

The problem is the first label '01 Jun' is NOT located under the first tick but on the second tick instead.

Is there a way to force the label under the first tick?
I have tried changing the grid option 'minBorderMargin' to no avail.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the labels are under the ticks. You can see that when you change the ticklength:

```
tickLength: 5,
```

Do you mean the ticks (and therefore ticklabels) are not under the bars? Of course they are not, because you have one bar every day and one tick every 1.9 days.

If you want a label every three days, you have to set the ticksize to three days:

```
tickSize: [3.0, "day"],
```

And if you want the first tick to be under the first bar, you have to set a minimum value for the axis:

```
min: gd(2018, 6, 1)
```

See this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zrtgqpk6/1/) for a full example.